# Azure function uses incorrect DLL version

Tags: c#, azure-functions, webhooks, dynamics-365

I have created an Azure function that is called via webhook from Dynamics 365. A simple scenario to read the remote context object does work; however, a more complex scenario throws an error. Tried to get an instance of the Dynamics service object using CrmServiceClient (Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector) but it throws an error when this line runs `CrmServiceClient client = new CrmServiceClient(crmConnectionString)`:

*"Could not load type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior' from assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.14.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"*

I have checked the DLLs in the bin directory in Azure and the version for Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is 2.22.

Also, I checked the xxx.deps.json file in Azure and it shows the same version:

```
"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.22.0.0": {
        "runtime": {
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "2.22.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "2.22.30211.1727"
          }
        }
```

I have searched for version 3.14.2.11 for the mentioned DLL but cannot find it. So I wonder why is Azure loading that version?

Following the advice of some other postings, I have added a file -function.proj- under my function's folder with the idea to downgrade the version of that DLL that Azure loads, here's the content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="2.22.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately, it hasn't changed the outcome. Has anyone run into the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just downgrading the runtime to version 1 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The package [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/9.0.2.25) is depend on `.net framework 4.6.2`, while your azure function TargetFramework is `netstandard 2.0`. So make sure your function's runtime version.

Then upgrade `Microsoft.IndentityModel.Client.ActiveDirectory` to **2.28.3 version**.

If your function runtime is ~1, create `project.json` with following content.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "2.28.3"
      }
    }
}
```

If your function runtime is ~2, create function.proj as below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IndentityModel.Client.ActiveDirectory" Version="2.28.3"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The function's runtime is 2. We already have a function.proj as it was described in the posting. We are referring to the right version (2.22.0) which works in other environments. By the way, version 2.28.3 is for the Windows phone.